# How can I install Mysql on Debian 10 (buster)?

Tags: debian, apt, mysql

I've tried to follow the [official guidance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install) on installing MySQL on a fresh Debian install.

So I went to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/, downloaded mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb,

Run through the installer options with

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

...which *seems* to work (albeit with a warning):

> (Reading database ... 32947 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb …
>   Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.13-1) over (0.8.13-1) …
>   Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.13-1) …
>   Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
>   OK

I do my

```
sudo apt update
```

Which again, seems to give sensible output:

> Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39.1 kB]
>   Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
>   Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
>   Hit:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
>   Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease
>   Fetched 88.4 kB in 1s (85.1 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   All packages are up to date.

Things start to go wrong when I get to step 2, as running

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Fails with output:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

So what am I doing wrong that is stopping this from working?

I've checked `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`, and that looks sensible:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-8.0
```

The output from  `apt-cache policy mysql-server` is

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: Please can you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` or the appropriate equivalent. (I'm interested in the deb configuration, so `grep -r mysql /etc/apt/sources*` would work, too.)

Comment: @roaima it looks sane to me, but have added to the question :)

Comment: What is the output of `$ apt-cache policy mysql-server` ?

Comment: @Jona that looks a little odd to me, as I'd expect _something_ to be showing as a candidate and something in the version table :/

Comment: What is your type of architecture (i386 or amd64 or ...) ?

Comment: @jona It's a Xeon E5620 (so i686)

Comment: What is the ouput of `uname -r` ?

Comment: @Jona `4.19.0-5-686-pae`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `dpkg --print-architecture` ?

Comment: See, that gives `i386`, which you'd think would count as supported

Comment: An option is to try this : https://askubuntu.com/a/43281

Comment: Mmm. I've just seen you're running i386 rather than x64. I wonder if that's the problem: that MySQL is not really supported on 32-bit Buster? (Or it's a packaging bug.)

Comment: The package you want to install is **mysql-community-server**

Answer (score 6):

Their repository is broken for your request.

Compare this file (0k):

http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-8.0/binary-i386/Packages

to this one (26k) :

http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages

or this one (3k):

http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-tools/binary-i386/Packages

i.e. : The first 'Packages' file is empty; and it is not normal : https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#A.22Packages.22_Indices

Comment: This should have been chosen as the correct answer. As opposed to the other answers, it explains why the installation failed for the OP, instead of trying to persuade him to install MariaDB (which he clearly does not want to do).

Answer (score 5):

To install the Debian provided packages, remove the repository that was installed from dev.mysql.com, and then this command should work:

`apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client`

MariaDB is the new name for the non-Oracle MySQL.

If you prefer to use the Oracle MySQL, then you just need to get the proper package name for the version you wish to install.  Check the output of `apt search mysql-server` to see what is available (in their packaging, they seem to put the version as part of the name).

Comment: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, which is still going strong. Your post doesn't explain how to install MySQL.

Comment: The poster was half-way to installing Oracle MySQL already, they just did not have the proper package name.  I do not know what version they want to use, so could not recommend a name but instead gave a command where they could see the available versions.

Comment: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages implies the package name is correct, but apt isn't seeing it for me :/

Comment: (or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#repo-qg-apt-repo-manual-setup, if you prefer)

Comment: The OP clearly wants to install the original MySQL instead of the MariaDB replacement. But the command shown above will install MariaDB and thus does the opposite of what the OP wanted. Plus, `apt search mysql-server` will find two packages: `default-mysql-server` and `default-mysql-server-core`. If you install them, you get MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me on buster:

```
apt-get install default-mysql-server
```

Comment: Funny thing; when I ran this, `apt` tried to install a bunch of mariadb packages including mariadb-client-10.3 and mariadb-server-10.3. I wonder if this installs mariadb instead, but in some sort of mysql-compatible mode.

Comment: I believe that this answer is plain wrong. The OP clearly wants to install the original MySQL instead of the MariaDB replacement. But the command shown above will install MariaDB and thus does the opposite of what the OP wanted.

Comment: This worked for me using debian in wsl 2