# Hello i have this error : dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: apt

I'm new here, i hope you can help me. I'm trying to install a mumble server on debian 10. Actually when i run the first commands to install mumble i have this : (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease         
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libmysqlclient21 : Depends:
  mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.26-1debian10) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried apt --fix-broken install

it returns this:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-community-client-plugins amd64 8.0.26-1debian10 [1108 kB]
    Fetched 1108 kB in 1s (1550 kB/s)                       
    (Reading database ... 56238 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.26-1debian10_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking mysql-community-client-plugins (8.0.26-1debian10) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.26-1debian10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_ldap_sasl_client.so', which is also in package mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins_8.0.25-1debian10
    dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.26-1debian10_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thank you

Comment: My guess is that you violate [this requirement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-upgrading): "instructions assume that MySQL has been installed on your system using the MySQL APT repository". Are you sure you need repo.mysql.com in you repository list?

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you for your answer. I just followed tutorials to install mysql ( many and many tutorials because they failed many times ). How to know if i used the MYSQL APT repository? How to know if i need repo.mysql.com in my repository?
Thank you

Comment: You know that you used repo.mysql.com because it appears in the output of the `apt-get update` command. I don't think you need it (to be honest, I don't even know why or when somebody would need it). Remove it from the apt sources and try again. Perhaps you first have to delete all MYSQL-related packages, though.

Comment: Stackexchange contains [a very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536538/how-can-i-install-mysql-on-debian-10-buster). You may be better off with MariaDB, which is identical to MySQL for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks! that worked.